# android, I try to find what type of number(from contact) is (mobile, home,work)

Tags: android

```
String tmp = txtPhoneName.getText().toString();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,  "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + tmp + "'", null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {     
    String contactId = Cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 

    while (phones.moveToNext()) {   
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        number1 = number;
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));  

        switch (type) {    
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
            // do something with the Home number here...  
                break;          
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:    
                // do something with the Mobile number here...   
                break;            
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:   
                // do something with the Work number here... 
                break;           
        }   
    }    
    phones.close();
}
```

My issue is that when it is at the switch statment it doesn't check anything. It goes to the while(phones.moveToNext()) where is my error does Phone.TYPE_HOME is not int and my type can't compare to it... And one last question, why for some contacts it gets the mobile number and for others the home (and in both cases the contacts have a home and a mobile number)? I want to get a number that starts with 07 and if there is no that kind of number to get whatever number there is for the contact, and then how to call that number... THX

Comment: I suspect it does check the type of number, but Android has more than these three types of numbers.  Check `TYPE_...` constants in this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Phones.html - to make sure, add `default` to your `switch` statement with some code there - it will be executed if none of the previous three types match.  By the way, when I imported contacts from my old nokia S40 phone, all numbers came as `TYPE_CUSTOM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because u haven put anything yet in the cases, try with int i=0; and see in the debugger

Answer (score 11):

Here i am going to show you that how to get home,mobile and work phone no of any contact, First of all u get an uri of any contact_id and then use below method to get all phone type nos.

```
while (phone_crsr.moveToNext()) 
{ 
 int phone_type = phone_crsr.getInt(phone_crsr.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));  
  switch (phone_type) 
     {    
      case Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
       phone_home =phone_crsr.getString(phone_crsr.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
       Toast.makeText(this, "home"+phone_home, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;          
      case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:     
       phone_mob=phone_crsr.getString(phone_crsr.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
       Toast.makeText(this, "mob"+phone_mob, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
       break;            
      case Phone.TYPE_WORK:                                  
       phone_work=phone_crsr.getString(phone_crsr.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
       Toast.makeText(this, "work"+phone_work, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;           
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have got `Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM`

you can try the below statement for fetching the custom label.

```
phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL)))
```